# Calling generic method from viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, mvvm

I'm pretty new to generics, and MVVM as well. Working on this for a project at school, and my problem might be that I'm trying to impress a bit much. I think I may have coded myself into a hole, but I'm hoping you all can help me get out of it.

I've created a dbcontext, a dataservice, and now I'm trying to get them to play nicely in my viewmodel - I'm getting nowhere.

DbContextFactory:

```
    public class TimeKeeprDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TimeKeeprDbContext>
{
    public TimeKeeprDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args = null)
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TimeKeeprDbContext>();
        options.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TimeKeeprDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");

        return new TimeKeeprDbContext(options.Options);
    }
}
```

DbContext:

```
    public class TimeKeeprDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TimeKeeprDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

DataService:

```
    public class DataService<T> : IDataService<T> where T: DomainObject
{
    private readonly TimeKeeprDbContextFactory _contextFactory;
    public DataService(TimeKeeprDbContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }
    public async Task<T> Create(T entity)
    {
        using TimeKeeprDbContext context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        EntityEntry<T> createdResult = await context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return createdResult.Entity;
    } [...]
```

BaseViewModel:

```
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region WindowProperties
    [.....]
    #endregion
    #region PropertyChanged

    protected void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action)
    {
        var propertyName = GetPropertyName(action);
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
    private static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action)
    {
        var expression = (MemberExpression)action.Body;
        var propertyName = expression.Member.Name;
        return propertyName;
    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion
}
```

ViewModel:

```
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _firstname;
    private string _lastname;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get => _firstname;
        set 
        {
            _firstname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => FirstName);
        }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get => _lastname;
        set
        {
            _lastname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => LastName);
        }
    }

    public ICommand CreateCommand { get { return new BaseCommand(Click); } }

    private void Click()
    {
        User user = new User()
        {
            FirstName = _firstname,
            LastName = _lastname
        };

        //call Create<T> from DataService

        ShowMessageBox($"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}"); //just to make sure the object is ok
    }
}
```

I've tried about a million things, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around what I need to do in order to call 'Create(user)' from DataService in the viewmodel. Can someone maybe point me in the right direction?

PS I've googled until my fingers bled, but it hasn't helped that much, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell because I don't know all the frameworks or nuget packages you are using.  But from what I can see, you just need to instantiate your DataService somewhere in your MainViewModel, then call its `Create` method where you've placed your comment `//call Create<T> from DataService`.

```
//Instantiate your DataService somewhere
var service = new DataService<User>(new TimeKeeprDbContextFactory());
//call Create<T> from DataService
service.Create(user);
```

If you see a squigly line under `service.Create(user)` indicating that this call is not awaited, you can fix that by making your function async/await like this.

````
private async void Click()
{
    User user = new User()
    {
        FirstName = _firstname,
        LastName = _lastname
    };

    //Instantiate your DataService somewhere
    var service = new DataService<User>(new TimeKeeprDbContextFactory());
    //call Create<T> from DataService
    await service.Create(user);

    ShowMessageBox($"{user.FirstName} {user.LastName}"); //just to make sure the object is ok}```
}
````

Comment: You're now officially my favourite person in the whole world!

I was REALLY close but I forgot to add the "new" in front of TimeKeeprDbContextFactory(), which gave me a whole long list of other errors.

HUGE thanks :)